# How do I use respond_with with custom classes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a JSON API with Rails and it seemed to work fine except for when I use `respond_with` custom classes (not an ActiveRecord inherited one).

Here is my class:

```
class JsonResponse
  def initialize(data, status)
    @data = data
    @status = status
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    {
      :data => @data,
      :status => @status
    }
  end
end
```

which is a simple response wrapper. When I try doing this:

```
def create
  unless(Match.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id]))
    Match.create(:user_id => params[:user_id])
  end
  time_response = JsonResponse.new("5", "success")
  respond_with(time_response)
end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for JsonResponse:Class):
  app/controllers/matches_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Any ideas? `respond_with` is driving me crazy.

Comment: did a little clean up to make it more readable and the title into a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your class should response to to_json method
2. Obviously set :location option in respond_with method. Rails try to create restful route from the object you pass to the method, but because your object is not resource, the error is raised.

Comment: But how do you add the appropriate response status? Passing an `ActiveRecord` object to `respond_with` seems to automatically detect wether it's a valid record or not. How do I make this with a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but I do not see respond_to...
respond_with works together with respond_to...

```
 respond_to :html, :xml, :json
```

This can be defined on Controller level

example:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    respond_with(@users = User.all)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
    respond_with(@user, :location => users_url)
  end
end
```

and then you can define your json template... don't know if you leave the json template empty if it takes your "JSONResponse" class...

just a thought...

Comment: i had the respond_to, I just didn't show that part of the controller